# Implementing google login flutter gives 12500 error

Tags: flutter

I implemented google login in flutter without using firebase in flutter (google cloud console). It was working in apk then later I needed push notification service for which I used firebase (fcm token and all) then I released the app to playstore but google login does not work. I keep getting apiexception error. Has anybody faced this issue? if yes any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a specific answer to your problem but I have also faced this problem once, I accidentally resolved it though.

But Error 12500 is a general error code that may occur when attempting to use the Google Sign-In feature and is caused by a few potensial issues:

1. An issue with the SHA-1 fingerprint of your app's signing
   certificate: To use Google Sign-In, you need to configure your app's
   SHA-1 fingerprint and package name in the Firebase console. Make
   sure that the fingerprint and package name you have configured in
   the Firebase console match the ones you are using to sign your app.
2. An issue with the Google Services configuration file: Make sure you
   have properly added the Google Services configuration file to your
   app.
3. An issue with the Google Play Services library: Make sure you have
   the latest version of the Google Play Services library installed in
   your app.
4. An issue with the device or emulator you are using: Make sure you
   are testing on a device or emulator that has Google Play Services
   installed and is up to date.

Possible fixes to try/check:

1. Double-check the SHA-1 fingerprint and package name: Make sure that
   the SHA-1 fingerprint and package name you have configured in the
   Firebase console match the ones you are using to sign your app.
2. Make sure you have added the Google Services configuration file: The
   Google Services configuration file is required for your app to
   communicate with Google services, including Google Sign-In. Make
   sure you have properly added this file to your app.
3. Update the Google Play Services library: Make sure you have the
   latest version of the Google Play Services library installed in your
   app. You can check for updates by going to the "SDK Manager" in
   Android Studio.
4. Test on a device or emulator with Google Play Services installed:
   Make sure you are testing on a device or emulator that has Google
   Play Services installed and is up to date.

I hope this helps! I will quickly search if I can find any other solution.

Comment: My main issue is that I am not using firebase for google login, firebase is used for fcm. I updated all the sha1 keys as well but to no avail.